# Use the Maclaurin series for $\cos(x)$to compute the value of $\cos(5^\circ)$ correct to five decimal places.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

So we have been given a table for the Maclaurin series of $\cos(x)$ but I'm not sure how to even start with this problem.

Here is the problem:

Use the Maclaurin series for $\cos(x)$to compute the value of $\cos(5^\circ)$ correct to five decimal places.

And we were giving the following hint:

Hints: Remember that the Maclaurin series assumes that the angle is in radians, not     degrees. Also, since the Maclaurin series for $\cos(x)$ is alternating and decreasing in     magnitude for small $x$, the error in using a partial sum of the series for the sum is less     than the first term in the series omitted.

Can you please help me to get started on this?

Comment: For starters, how do you convert from degree to radians, and vice-a-versa?

Comment: Do you know about [Lagrange's Remainder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are computing $\cos(\pi/36)$.  The Taylor series at 0 is an alternating series, so the error you encounter is at worst the magnitude of the last term.  So, you must find $n$ so 
$$(\pi/36)^{2n}/(2n)! < 5\cdot 10^{-6}.$$
Since $\pi/36 < 1/10$ this should not be hard.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: (1) In radians $x = \pi/36$. (2) To guarantee five decimal places, the error needs to be less than $\varepsilon = 5 \times 10^{-6}$. (3) You need to find the first positive integer $n$ such that $$\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!} < \varepsilon.$$Then add up all the terms you have. Don't forget the $(-1)^n$.